# How to obtain EJB remote been deployed on a remote server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Let's say someone created am `EJB` and deployed it in an app server.

How do I go about calling that `EJB` if I don't have the remote code?

Is it possible? Or is it normally I should obtain the EJB remote first?

Comment: You want to access the EJB within the application server or from outside the application server?

Comment: Outside the application server.

Comment: You should use `InitialContext#lookup`, validating also that the `EJB` provides a `remote interface` and that it's registered in the application server's `JNDI` tree.